# Is there an Upsert API call to create/ update a subscriber in 1 API call?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketo

Is there an Upsert API call to create/ update a subscriber in 1 API call?
It will save us a lot of resources.

Comment: Please refrain to asking duplicate questions, as you have also posted this one: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/307208/is-there-an-option-to-create-and-opt-in-a-user-in-the-same-api-call

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Subscribers.Upsert](https://www.salesforcefan.com/post/add-update-all-subscribers-from-data-extension-via-ssjs) function in SSJS to upsert All subscriber list.

Additional reference from my blog- https://www.salesforcefan.com/post/add-update-all-subscribers-from-data-extension-via-ssjs

**Edit Post comments:**

Adding the subscriber list in all - subscriber is still in SOAP API so you might need to do create and update call separately.

But, You can use the following approach (not recommendable in terms of security) if you really have a constrain on API calls etc..

From Salesforce you would need to call the cloud page with encrypted additional parameters like subscriberkey, emails and other attributes which is needed for all subscriber list.

You can create a cloud page, get the parameters via encrypted URL,decrypt it and add the  attributes to subscribers.Upsert function as mentioned above to add/update the all subscriber list.

Comment: thanks Naveen, but we need a SOAP/ REST API call. As this is part of an integration of SF.

Comment: Hi @yoni349 can you please update your question properly with what issue you are facing?. Which integration you are talking about? From SF to SFMC or from SFMC to SF?

Comment: we are using Workato to integrate from SF to SFMC. The system executes SFMC API calls.

Comment: Have edited my answer. Let me know if you need anything.

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking of using the API to trigger an automation that will execute SSJS code that will do all the needed. It sounds safer than a public cloud page.

Comment: Yes you can use an API to trigger an automation for bulk. I wouldn't suggest you to trigger automation for every record. Also am just curious how will you pass the parameter from SF to SFMC SSJS?

Comment: Since the API to add/update a DE is very simple, I was thinking of using workato to update a DE then trigger the automation that will use the DE as a source of truth to do the needed. About your previous note, do you think that with the DE solution it will work well? I'm triggering automation it once every 15 min.

Comment: If you make DE as source then you can only schedule the automation for every one hour only as the minimum duration. I would suggest first decide the approach how you want to do it. Try with your approach come back if you have any questions.