# Is there an option to create and Opt-in a user in the same API call?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Is there an option to create and Opt-in a user in the same API call? 
At the moment I can find it only in 2 separate calls.
Create then Opt-in to a keyword.

It will save us a lot of resources.

Comment: Are you speaking of opt-in in the context of Mobile Studio and SMS? As it is not 100% clear from your question, I just derive it from you referring to a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

you could write your functionality on a secured Cloudpage with SSJS and AMPScript.
Be advised, this might not save you time in the short run as you'll need some initial effort to set this up.

In any case, this should get you started:
http://www.devsutd.com/writing-a-rest-service-using-cloud-pages/

In terms of authentication - you can employ "getTokenContext" method to verify a marketing cloud API token, and then only process data that came with a valid token.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/gettokencontext.htm

Do your due diligence in terms of load and usecase scenarios, but in general, this approach can greatly reduce the complexity in an outside integration.